# What is the get/post command to ping web services with website update?

Tags: c#, web-services, wordpress, ping

Wordpress has an ability to notify a list of web services that a new publication has been made. Here are few examples of a ping service:

http://blogsearch.google.com/ping/RPC2

What are the proper commands to ping this kind of service and other similar services?

I'm going to use this from c# code.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is based on XML-RPC - for some details and sample source see:

- http://www.keyvan.ms/how-to-implement-trackback-handler-in-asp-net
- http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback